# Coding a calculator but having problem with the arrays in the calculate function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to code a calculator, but I'm having a problem with the calculate function.
I want to be able to take more than two numbers and calculate the answer, but I can't work my way around it

```js
        class Calculator {
            constructor(currText, prevText) {
                this.currText = currText;
                this.prevText = prevText;
            }


            calcInput() {
                for (let i = 0; i < operators.length; i++) {
                    let result;

                    if (operators[i] == "*") {
                        result = parseInt(numbers[i]) * parseInt(numbers[i+1])
                        numbers.splice(numbers[0], 2, result);
                        operators.splice(operators[0], 1);
                    }

                    // if (operators[0] == "+") {
                    //     result = parseInt(numbers[i]) + parseInt(numbers[i + 1])
                    // }

                    // if (operators[0] == "-") {
                    //     result = parseInt(numbers[i]) - parseInt(numbers[i + 1])
                    // }

                    // if (operators[0] == "÷") {
                    //     result = parseInt(numbers[i]) / parseInt(numbers[i + 1])
                    // }
                    console.log(result, numbers)
                }
                // this.clearInput()
                // this.updateDisplay(result)
            }
            deleteInput() {

            }

            clearInput() {
                currText.innerHTML = ""
                prevText.innerHTML = ""
            }

            updateDisplay(digit) {
                currText.innerHTML = currText.innerHTML.toString() + digit.toString()
                numbers = currText.innerHTML.split(/\+|\-|\*|\÷/g)
                operators = currText.innerHTML.replace(/[0-9]|\./g, "").split("")
            }
        }
        let numbers;
        let operators;

        let prevText = document.querySelector(".up_screen")
        let currText = document.querySelector(".down_screen")

        let clearKey = document.getElementById("clear")
        let deleteKey = document.getElementById("delete")
        let resultKey = document.getElementById("result")

        let calcKeys = document.querySelectorAll(".calc_key")
        let mathKeys = document.querySelectorAll(".math_key")
        let numKeys = document.querySelectorAll('.num_key')

        const calculator = new Calculator(currText, prevText)

        numKeys.forEach(button => {
            button.addEventListener('click', () => {
                calculator.updateDisplay(button.innerHTML)
            })
        })

        mathKeys.forEach(button => {
            button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                let lastChar = currText.innerHTML[currText.innerHTML.length - 1]

                if (lastChar === "+" || lastChar === "-" || lastChar === "*" || lastChar === "÷") {
                    currText.innerHTML = currText.innerHTML.substring(0, currText.innerHTML.length - 1) + e.target.innerHTML
                } else if (currText.innerHTML.length == 0) {
                    console.log("Enter number");
                } else {
                    calculator.updateDisplay(button.innerHTML)
                }
            })
        })

        resultKey.addEventListener("click", () => {
            calculator.calcInput()
            // calculator.updateDisplay()
        })

        clearKey.addEventListener("click", () => {
            calculator.clearInput()
        })
```

```css
  html {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin: 0;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
            overflow: hidden;
            min-height: 100vh;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .box {
            border: 2px solid black;
            background-color: dimgrey;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            width: 320px;
            height: 380px;
            justify-content: space-evenly;
            border-radius: 15px;
            padding: 10px 0;
        }

        .display {
            border: 2px solid darkslategrey;
            width: 85%;
            height: 30%;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: flex-end;
            justify-content: flex-end;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 2.5rem;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .up_screen,
        .down_screen {
            width: 100%;
            height: 50%;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: end;
            /* overflow: scroll; */
        }

        .up_screen {
            background-color: lightgray;
            color: darkcyan;
        }

        .down_screen {
            background-color: lightcyan;
        }

        .keypad {
            width: 90%;
            height: 60%;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-evenly;
        }

        .keyrow {
            display: flex;
            width: 90%;
            justify-content: space-around;
        }

        button {
            width: 60px;
            height: 40px;
            background-color: white;
            font-size: 1.5rem;
        }

        .special_keys {
            flex: auto;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="box">
        <div class="display">
            <div class="up_screen"></div>
            <div class="down_screen"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="keypad">
            <div class="keyrow row1">
                <button class="num_key">7</button>
                <button type="button" class="calc_key num_key">8</button>
                <button type="button" class="calc_key num_key">9</button>
                <button type="button" class="calc_key math_key">+</button>
            </div>

            <div class="keyrow row2">
                <button type="button" class="calc_key num_key">4</button>
                <button type="button" class="calc_key num_key">5</button>
                <button type="button" class="calc_key num_key">6</button>
                <button type="button" class="calc_key math_key">-</button>
            </div>

            <div class="keyrow row3">
                <button type="button" class="calc_key num_key">1</button>
                <button type="button" class="calc_key num_key">2</button>
                <button type="button" class="calc_key num_key">3</button>
                <button type="button" class="calc_key math_key">÷</button>
            </div>

            <div class="keyrow row4">
                <button type="button" class="calc_key num_key">.</button>
                <button type="button" class="calc_key num_key">0</button>
                <button type="button" id="result">=</button>
                <button type="button" class="calc_key math_key">*</button>
            </div>

            <div class="keyrow row5 ">
                <button class="special_keys" id="clear">C</button>
                <button class="special_keys" id="delete">Del</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My idea is to work with two numbers at a time and accumulate the till the final answer.
I've tried using for loop with splice and I've tried reduce method.
I just realized that the numbers array I'm working with isn't splicing the way I want to.

And also, I'm trying to find a way to remove "currText.innerHTML" and place it in a variable. But everything I've used doesn't reflect on the calculator screen. I left it to continue with the project, but I'll appreciate help there too.
Please help.

Comment: _"I'm trying to find a way to remove "currText.innerHTML" and place it in a variable"_ - what exactly do you mean by that? You want something like `let foo = currText.innerHTML`, and then be able to do `foo = ...` to set the innerHTML of that element? No, that won't work. Only objects are passed by reference in JavaScript, but not scalar values. You can do the first part to let `foo` _get_ the current innerHTML of the element assigned; but you can't use it in the "other direction", to assign new innerHTML to the actual element.

Comment: Maybe instead of input field with text, you can use input field with number? that helps you to collect only numbers from user. Every time user presses an operator, you save the number and operation in variables, then you empty your input field and collect the next input.

Comment: I thought of that, but I wasn't sure how to implement it.
And i felt like I'd run into the same issue because that's not actually the root issue.

Comment: I suggest tackling one problem at a time. _"the numbers array ... isn't splicing the way I want to."_ how do you want it to splice? What are your inputs, and what is your expected vs actual output? You may be able to find an existing answer for this issue.

Comment: If i have an input of 8 * 6 +5
I want to collect the numbers in an array [8,6,5] and the operands in another[*,+]. Then do the math in the numbers array depending on the order in the operands array to get a final answer